# Add all numbers in row

Tags: php, mysql, math

I have a database like this:

```
ID    |    AMOUNT 
1           15.00
2          100.00
3          100.00
```

I need to add all the amounts together.   I have tried some PHP math stuff but just can't make it work.

```
<?php
$total = mysql_query("SELECT amount FROM payments") 
or die(mysql_error()); 

$grandtotal=   
    while($total1 = mysql_fetch_array( $total )) {

$total1['amount']+


};

?>
```

Comment: Try `$total1['amount']++` and remove the semicolon after the last curly brace.

Comment: why don't do it in the sql query

Comment: `SELECT SUM(amount) AS amount_sum FROM payments`

Comment: I am still learning MySQL and didn't even know that math inside the sql was possible!!  Thanks to all of you!!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(amount) as sum_amount FROM payments
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions for the specific task you're trying to accomplish:

```
while($total1 = mysql_fetch_array( $total )) {

$total1['amount']++; //returns Returns $total1['amount'], then increments it by one.

} // <-- semicolon removed
```

---

As Mark Baker suggested in comments, you could do it from within your SQL query using `SUM`:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) AS amount_sum FROM payments
```